# Distance between two cities

Tags: geography, distance

I need help calculating the distance between 2 cities in Wolfram MAthematica. I would need to create two drop-down lists of European capitals. After selecting any two cities from the lists, I would need to calculate the distance between these cities. I tried using GeoDistance, but I can't use it for two city lists.
Thank you very much for your help !
Thera

Answer (score 11):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

countries = EntityList@EntityClass["Country", "Europe"];

capitals = #["CapitalCity"] & /@ countries;

Manipulate[
 Column[{
   distance[start, end, UnitSystem -> units],
   GeoGraphics[{Red, Thick,
     Polygon[countries[[Position[capitals, start][[1, 1]]]]],
     Polygon[countries[[Position[capitals, end][[1, 1]]]]],
     If[distance === GeoDistance,
      GeoPath[{start, end}],
      Line[TravelDirections[{start, end}]]]},
    ImageSize -> Medium]}],
 {{start, capitals[[-2]]},
  Thread[capitals ->
    (Last /@ capitals)[[All, {1, 3}]]]},
 {{end, capitals[[18]]},
  Thread[capitals ->
    (Last /@ capitals)[[All, {1, 3}]]]},
 {{units, "Metric"}, {"Metric", "Imperial"}},
 {{distance, GeoDistance}, {GeoDistance, TravelDistance}}]
```

[image]
[image]